# Write a program that asks the user to type in 5 numbers , and that outputs the largest of these numbers and the smallest of these numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Write a program that asks the user to type in 5 numbers , and that outputs the largest of these numbers and the smallest of these numbers. So for example if the user types in the numbers 2456 457 13 999 35 the output will be as follows :
the largest number is 2456
the smallest number is 35

In Python

```
a = input()
first = int(a)
b = input()
second = int(b)
c = input()
third = int(c)
d = input()
fourth = int(d)
if a > b or a > c or a > d:
  print ('the larges number' + a)
elif a < b or a < c or a < d:
  print ('the smallest number' +a )
elif b > a or b > c or b > d:
  print ('the larges number' + b)
elif b < a or b < c or b < d:
  print ('the smallest number is' + b )
elif d > a or d > b or d > c:
  print ('the biggest number is' + d )
elif d < a or d < b or d < c:
  print ('the smallest numbet is'+ d)
else:
```

I came up with this idea, but I dont think it works correctly

numbers, and that outputs the largest

of these numbers and the smallest of these numbers.

In my module handbook I have this example

```
num = 0

while num < 100:

num = num + 5

print(str(num))

print(’Done looping!’)
```

however after this , there is no further explanation of how do I solve the question. Could you please help me ?

I need to solve the question trough using while loops , 
I am very new to programing, please help.

Comment: Please do your homework yourself, that is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Dear Patrick , I dont know how to do it
Thats why I kindly ask for help, I learning programing for myself
@PatrickHund

Comment: Please read [ask] - you have to show at least some effort. Try to write the code, when you run into problems, post your code, describe the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve it by doing the `input` in a loop and then use the builtin min and max function to display the largest and smallest:

```
inputs = [int(input()) for _ in range(5)]
print(min(inputs), max(inputs))
```

It seems you need a `while` loop, in that case just use a counter:

```
loopcount = 0
largest = -float('inf')  # smallest possible value
smallest = float('inf')  # largest possible value
while loopcount < 5:
    loopcount = loopcount + 1

    given = input()
    given_as_integer = int(given)

    # Compare to the current smallest and largest value
    if given_as_integer < smallest:
        smallest = given_as_integer
    if given_as_integer > largest:
        largest = given_as_integer

print('the largest number is', largest)
print('the smallest number is', smallest)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer . @MSeifert , could you please explain me how can I do it the manner below? I really need to understand it in this way. 
I have this example on tom of my exercise 

num = 0

while num < 100:

num = num + 5

print(str(num))

print(’Done looping!’)

Comment: @stefans I don't understand, do you want a `while` loop? The question didn't specify anything like that. You might want to consider editing the question including all the requirements.

Comment: @stefans I updated the answer. Let me know if that answers the question. However I would stick with the first approach (it's just more elegant to have a comprehension and using built-in functions).

Comment: thank you for ur reply, yes , this answers the question , I just had to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice way to do it, without too much code, and the user should separate numbers with `space`:

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, input().split())
print("Largest number is {}".format(max(a, b, c, d)))
print("Smallest number is {}".format(min(a, b, c, d)))
```

`map` will change all `input` to `int` and `split()` will break it into numbers by using `space` as delimiter.

`max` will give you the maximum of the sequence `a, b, c, d` making `min` into minimum of the same sequence.

If you want to go into loop, this is one way to do it:

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, input().split())
myNumbers = [a, b, c, d]
minimum = False
maximum = False

for number in myNumbers:
    if not (minimum and maximum):
        minimum, maximum = number, number
    elif number < minimum:
        minimum = number
    elif number > maximum:
        maximum = number

print("Largest number is {}".format(maximum))
print("Smallest number is {}".format(minimum))
```

Comment: Dear @zipa could you please explain me how do I do it by using loops ?

Comment: @stefans I added one way to do it in loop

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you are after, enjoy and good luck.

```
loopnumber = 0
while loopnumber <=4:
    print('please insert 5 numbers: ', end='')
    num = input()
    loopnumber = loopnumber + 1
    if loopnumber != 1:
        if int(num) < int(smallest):
            smallest = num
        else:
            smallest = smallest
    if loopnumber != 1:
        if int(num) > int(largest):
            largest = num
        else:
            largest = largest
    else:
        smallest = num
        largest = num
print ('Done looping, smallest number is ' + str(smallest) + ", largest number is " +" "+ str(largest))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print("Please key in five numbers: ")
num1 = input (">")
num2 = input (">")
num3 = input (">")
num4 = input (">")
num5 = input (">")

x = max (num1, num2, num3, num4, num5)
y = min (num1, num2, num3, num4, num5)
print ("largest number is " + x)
print ("smallest number is " + y)

#you will have to add a while loop in this I think it comes for asking input
```

## I am fairly new at coding so this was the simplest and best solution I could come up with

Comment: You should always try to include some test input and output to demonstrate that your code is working.  But more importantly, Stack Overflow is not for helping people do their homework.  If you want to collaborate with another student so you can both learn something (a good goal!), try other sites, like https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/