# Basic while loop program

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been self-teaching Python for the last month. I have an interview for a coding course and need help on writing a program which uses a while loop.
The task is as follows:

Write a program that asks the user to type in 5 numbers, and that outputs the largest of these numbers and the smallest of these numbers. So, for example, if the user types in the numbers 2456 457 13 999 35, the output would be:

The largest number is 2456
The smallest number is 13

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you progress so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a program that asks the user to type in 5 numbers , and that outputs the largest of these numbers and the smallest of these numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834369/write-a-program-that-asks-the-user-to-type-in-5-numbers-and-that-outputs-the-l)

Comment: @KristopherJohnson: Not quite a dupe... that other question shows effort from the OP where as this one is a "do it all for me" question... close though, but try harder next time! ;)

Comment: this is for an interview, you may want to stop interviewing until you have a better grasp of the language? make an attempt at least.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
numbers = [] #this will be the list in which we will store the numbers
while len(numbers) < 5:  #len return the length of your list, we want our while loop to repeat 5 times
    numbers.append(double(input("enter number: "))) # adds the inputed number to the list
print("The largest number is",max(numbers),"The smallest number is",min(numbers))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Next time you ask questions, please include at least some of your progress so that everyone is willing to help you.
When you learn a language, a good coding style is also important.
Here is an answer for you. I hope you can learn something. You can also try using max() and min() with a list.

```
input_times = 5
max_num, min_num = -float('inf'), float('inf')
while input_times:
    input_times -= 1
    try:
        num = int(input('Please enter a number:\n'))
        if num < min_num:
            min_num = num
        if num > max_num:
            max_num = num
    except:
        print("Please input an integer!")
        input_times += 1
print('The largest number is {max_num} The smallest number is {min_num}'.format(
       max_num = max_num, min_num = min_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_min(): 
    my_list = []
    for i in range(1, 6):
        temp_val = input("Enter number {}: ".format(i))
        my_list.append(int(temp_val))
    max_val = max(my_list)
    min_val = min(my_list)
    return "max value is {} and min value is {}".format(max_val, min_val)


print(max_min())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!